# WS02 CEP Siddhi Queries

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

New to Siddhi CEP. Other than the regular docs on WS02 CEP can someone point to a good tutorial.

Here are our requirements. Point out some clues on the right ways of writing such queries.

- Have a single stream of sensor device notification ( IOT application ).
- Stream input is via REST-JSON and output is also to be formatted to REST-JSON. ( Hope this is possible on WS02 CEP 3.1)

Kind of execution plan required:
- If device notification reports usage of Sensor 1, then monitor to see if within 5 mins if device notification reports usage of Sensor 2 also. If found then generate output stream reporting composite-activity back on REST-JSON.
- If such composite-activity is not detected during a time slot in morning, afternoon and evening then generate warning-event-stream status on REST-JSON. ( So how to find events which did not occur in time ) 
- If such composite-activity is not found within some time slots in morning, afternoon and evening then report failure1-event-stream status back on REST-JSON.

This should work day on day, so how will the previous processed data get deleted in WSO2 CEP.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

The queries can be as follows (these are draft queries and may require slight modifications to get them running)

1. To detect sensor 1, and then sensor 2 within 5 minutes (assuming sensorStram has id, value) you can simply use a pattern like following with the 'within' keyword:

```
from e1=sensorStream[sensorId == '1'] -> e2=sensorStream[sensorId == '2']

select 'composite activity detected' as description, e1.value as sensor1Value, e2.value as sensor2Value

within 5 minutes

insert into compositeActivityStream;
```

2. To detect non occurrences (id=1 arrives, but no id=2 within 5 minutes) we can have following two queries:

```
from sensorStream[sensorId == '1']#window.time(5 minutes)

select *

insert into delayedSensor1Stream for expired-events;


from e1=sensorStream[sensorId == '1'] -> nonOccurringEvent = sensorStream[sensorId == '2'] or delayedEvent=delayedSensor1Stream

select 'id=2 not found' as description, e1.value as id1Value, nonOccurringEvent.sensorId as nonOccurringId

having (not(nonOccurringId instanceof string))

insert into nonOccurrenceStream;
```

This will detect non-occurrences immediately at the end of 5 minutes after the arrival of id=1 event.
For an explanation of the above logic, have a look at the [non occurrence sample of cep 4.0.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Sample+0111+-+Detecting+non-occurrences+with+Patterns) (the syntax is a bit different, but the same idea)

3. Now since you need to periodically generate a report, we need another query. For convenience i assume you need a report every 6 hours (360 minutes) and use a time batch window here. Alternatively with the new CEP 4.0.0 you can use the 'Cron window' to generate this at specific times which is better for your use case.

```
from nonOccurrenceStream#window.timeBatch(360 minutes)

select count(id1Value) as nonOccurrenceCount

insert into nonOccurrenceReportsStream for expired-events;
```

You can use http input/output adaptors and do json mappings with json builders and formatters for this use case.